# Import error for icu in Mac and Ubuntu, although pyicu is installed correctly

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, pyicu

I have `pyicu` installed in both MacOS and Ubuntu 14.04 but it shows ImportError upon importing.
For MacOS high sierra output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/Users/siddharthdas/venvs/chai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/icu/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
  from _icu import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/siddharthdas/venvs/chai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_icu.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZNK6icu_6114Transliterator12getTargetSetERNS_10UnicodeSetE
 Referenced from: /Users/siddharthdas/venvs/chai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_icu.cpython-36m-darwin.so
 Expected in: flat namespace
in /Users/siddharthdas/venvs/chai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_icu.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

and on ubuntu 14.0 this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/home/hackathon/venvs/grey_worm/lib/python3.4/site-packages/icu/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
  from _icu import *
ImportError: libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same experience when building and installing the `pyicu` from source in my Mac High Sierra.

The error message `Symbol not found: __ZNK6icu_6114Transliterator12getTargetSetERNS_10UnicodeSetE` is a sign of shared library mismatch between the ICU version we are using and the one actually used when building the package (Mac has built-in ICU library in `/usr/library/libicucore.dylib` - which i suspect is used as default during build process).

So, i did the following to get the pyicu up and running with the correct icu lib:

1. Remove and reinstall icu4c using homebrew (`brew remove icu4c` and `brew install icu4c`)
2. Create a icu-config symlink in standard path (`ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/61.1/bin/icu-config /usr/local/bin/icu-config`)
3. Clone the pyicu from repo, edit the `setup.py` file and fill out the entries for 'darwin' under `INCLUDES`, `CFLAGS`, `LFLAGS`, `LIBRARIES` sections as follows:

   ```
   INCLUDES = {
       'darwin': ['/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/61.1/include']
   }

   CFLAGS = {
       'darwin': ['-DPYICU_VER="%s"' %(VERSION), '-std=c++11']
   }

   LFLAGS = {
       'darwin': ['-L/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/61.1/lib']
   }

   LIBRARIES = {
       'darwin': ['/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/61.1/lib']
   }
   ```
4. Build and install the package, i.e. `python3 setup.py build` and `python3 setup.py install`

Note: If you previously had tried (unsuccessfully) build the package, make sure that you clean out the content of the `build/` dir first before rebuilding, as the build process seems to skip the creation of new build files if it sees the directory populated with files from previous build.

Comment: The problem persists

Comment: what is the output of `otool -L /Users/siddharthdas/venvs/chai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_icu.cpython-36m-darwin.so` ?

Comment: `/Users/siddharthdas/venvs/chai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_icu.cpython-36m-darwin.so:
     /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 104.1.0)
     /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4)`

Comment: Seems like it's still missing libicu from icu4c. Please find output of the same command from my installation below:
 `/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.61.dylib (compatibility version 61.0.0, current version 61.1.0)
 /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.61.dylib (compatibility version 61.0.0, current version 61.1.0)
 /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicudata.61.1.dylib (compatibility version 61.0.0, current version 61.1.0)
 /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4)`

Comment: so what to do now?

Comment: Are you installing pyicu from source or from pip? I think you can try following my steps above if it’s from source. I haven’t reproduce it using pip

Comment: For me problem also persisted. I started over, and instead of `python3 setup.py install`, i ran `pip3 install -e .`, and it worked. no more `Symbol not found` error :) i've collected my findings here: https://gist.github.com/ddelange/6e04e81b99fae08e817a00515d4a378d

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me! Have been trying for many hours, and feels nice to finally have it working.

Comment: FWIW none of these instructions worked for me on MacOS Catalina. Wish I could throw PyICU through a plate glass window.

Answer (score -1):

When installing `pycu` latest version on macOS (64.2) against python2.7 I did in `setup.py` as described above:

```
INCLUDES = {
    'darwin': ['/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/64.2'],
    'linux': [],
    'freebsd': ['/usr/local/include'],
    'win32': ['c:/icu/include'],
    'sunos5': [],
    'cygwin': [],
}

CFLAGS = {
    'darwin': ['-DPYICU_VER="%s"' %(VERSION), '-std=c++11'],
    'linux': [],
    'freebsd': ['-std=c++11'],
    'win32': ['/Zc:wchar_t', '/EHsc'],
    'sunos5': ['-std=c++11'],
    'cygwin': ['-D_GNU_SOURCE=1', '-std=c++11'],
}

LFLAGS = {
    'darwin': ['-L/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/64.2/lib'],
    'linux': [],
    'freebsd': ['-L/usr/local/lib'],
    'win32': ['/LIBPATH:c:/icu/lib'],
    'sunos5': [],
    'cygwin': [],
}

LIBRARIES = {
    'darwin': ['/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/64.2/lib'],
    'linux': [],
    'freebsd': ['icui18n', 'icuuc', 'icudata'],
    'win32': ['icuin', 'icuuc', 'icudt'],
    'sunos5': ['icui18n', 'icuuc', 'icudata'],
    'cygwin': ['icui18n', 'icuuc', 'icudata'],
}
```

and for the build:

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

then I have got PyICU `2.3.1` installed:

```
Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyICU-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.14-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for PyICU==2.3.1
Finished processing dependencies for PyICU==2.3.1
```